# Angular7 SSR, webpack and splitChunks

Tags: angular, webpack, server-side-rendering

I try to split the main.js file on SSR with splitChunks, I use angular7 as SSR Universal, the main file is over 2MB.

The app, build and compile successfully with ssr, no errors. But doesn't work when I use server as `serve:ssr: node dist/server.js`,

I try all the configurations from splitChunks as "**all**", "**async**" or "**initial**" and no luck, works fine, when I exclude, chunks: 'xxx'

this is the splitChunk setting on `webpack.server.config.js`

```
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            name: true,
            cacheGroups: {
              vendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                priority: -10
              },
            }
          }
```

the error shows as:

```
        /Projects-TFVC/mg-web-angular-1/dist/server.js:20
        /******/                modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
                                                  ^

        TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
            at __webpack_require__ (/Projects-TFVC/mg-web-angular-1/dist/server.js:20:30)
```

files size:

```
        Time: 96243ms
    chunk {0} common.88e267b2fcbb907af89e.js, common.88e267b2fcbb907af89e.js.map (common) 56.9 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {1} runtime.3f1fd536463b60c38762.js, runtime.3f1fd536463b60c38762.js.map (runtime) 2.64 kB [entry] [rendered]
    chunk {2} 2.8d2bc8ca5f3c2bbab259.js, 2.8d2bc8ca5f3c2bbab259.js.map () 164 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {3} es2015-polyfills.f878a7ec2d17b7f461fb.js, es2015-polyfills.f878a7ec2d17b7f461fb.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 52.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {4} main.d2c194e830b69cd70fe3.js, main.d2c194e830b69cd70fe3.js.map (main) 1.58 MB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {5} polyfills.133ac64106205f40abf3.js, polyfills.133ac64106205f40abf3.js.map (polyfills) 89 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {6} styles.85fe7b4c6fb18fcdb1ea.js, styles.85fe7b4c6fb18fcdb1ea.js.map (styles) 485 kB [initial] [rendered]
    chunk {7} 7.3a0af0c5fb9a7ba92e61.js, 7.3a0af0c5fb9a7ba92e61.js.map () 600 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {8} 8.795570b9a4006c25c960.js, 8.795570b9a4006c25c960.js.map () 899 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {9} 9.17b1d842b6ae483a2f66.js, 9.17b1d842b6ae483a2f66.js.map () 28.1 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {10} 10.de68a4c762b503fa2a9f.js, 10.de68a4c762b503fa2a9f.js.map () 98.8 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {11} 11.59811db21c770451231d.js, 11.59811db21c770451231d.js.map () 104 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {12} 12.acf5ff35cdaea7c3ede0.js, 12.acf5ff35cdaea7c3ede0.js.map () 17.6 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {13} 13.bc89789523b05320f59d.js, 13.bc89789523b05320f59d.js.map () 110 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {14} 14.0b98432b5094a092fc99.js, 14.0b98432b5094a092fc99.js.map () 35 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {15} 15.89f1a48abda5fb2bd3ad.js, 15.89f1a48abda5fb2bd3ad.js.map () 690 bytes  [rendered]
    chunk {16} 16.84902a6a73aa51fa0c7a.js, 16.84902a6a73aa51fa0c7a.js.map () 68.9 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {17} 17.70c569dc88f4dbc504ba.js, 17.70c569dc88f4dbc504ba.js.map () 41.5 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {18} 18.d1d44e51221c073d69a9.js, 18.d1d44e51221c073d69a9.js.map () 88.7 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {19} 19.da59097f349811851768.js, 19.da59097f349811851768.js.map () 2.57 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {20} 20.b18b4760a4b16099ce69.js, 20.b18b4760a4b16099ce69.js.map () 247 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {21} 21.f2cc4ecfbba0062fa6e4.js, 21.f2cc4ecfbba0062fa6e4.js.map () 50.6 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {22} 22.63a61006700b3a111276.js, 22.63a61006700b3a111276.js.map () 2.28 kB  [rendered]
    chunk {scripts} scripts.2bbb0f7e81eb835e1cea.js, scripts.2bbb0f7e81eb835e1cea.js.map (scripts) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]

    WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial. Budget 2 MB was exceeded by 208 kB.
```

any ideas? I can't find any solution. 
I'll appreciate all your help.

Comment: If you use `lazy-loading` in your angular application dividing into different modules, by default they'll be converted into chunks.

Comment: I'm using lazy-loading, but the still too big the file, I add the list of the file size, have look. Check the file size of chunk {4} main...